# nodejs: (node:612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a discord bot (actually two, one's in python) that I run with my raspberry pi 4 4gb ram model. I made it so that it automatically executes js and python scripts on startup (via crontab) and places the output in a file.

When I try to send a embed via the bot i get this,:

```
(node:612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
    at MessageEmbed.setup (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:77:91)
    at new MessageEmbed (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:18:10)
    at embedLikes.map.e (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/APIMessage.js:164:40)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at APIMessage.resolveData (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/APIMessage.js:164:31)
    at TextChannel.send (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:166:62)
    at Client.client.on.message (/HOMENAS/KitBot/server.js:13:23)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
(node:612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:612) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fields.flat is not a function
    at Function.normalizeFields (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:443:8)
    at MessageEmbed.setup (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:77:91)
    at new MessageEmbed (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:18:10)
    at embedLikes.map.e (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/APIMessage.js:164:40)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at APIMessage.resolveData (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/APIMessage.js:164:31)
    at TextChannel.send (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/TextBasedChannel.js:166:62)
    at Client.client.on.message (/HOMENAS/KitBot/server.js:13:23)
    at Client.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/HOMENAS/KitBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
(node:612) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

**Note: /HOMENAS/KitBot is the directory where the bot's files are at (in my NAS SSD).**

I read that it may be something to do with the Node's version but I have v14.4.0 and I still get the error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node -v
v14.4.0
```

Do you guys have any idea on what the problem may be?

**EDIT:**
Here is my embed code (its a censoring mechanism) code:

```js
var forbidenWords = require('./profanewords.json');
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getHours();
client.on('message', message => {
  for (var i = 0; i < forbidenWords.length; i++) {
    if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes(forbidenWords[i]) && message.guild.id != 702111932848537622 ) {
      message.delete()
      const warnmsg = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setDescription(`Woah, **${message.author.username}**! This is a family friendly server. Don't use that language here!`)
      message.channel.send(warnmsg);
      break;
    } 
  }
});
```

profanewords.json contains a list of profane words

I know forbidenwords is misspelt and I will fix that later

Comment: As the error says, `fields.flat is not a function`. In order to help you we need you to add your code so that we can see what `fields.flat` is.

Comment: thanks! i added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is an issue with Discord.js when using a Node version above the LTS : https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/3910

Downgrading to Node's LTS version (Node 12) should solve the issue.
To easily change Node version, I suggest using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) or [NMV for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Comment: this works but every reboot it switches back to 14.4.0, will a shell script that has he command ``nvm use 12.18.1`` work?

Comment: I guess ? I've never had any issue with NVM. Maybe it's an issue with your path environment variable.